Pattern to set optional, nullable function argument to non-null
Is there any nice pattern to set an optional, nullable argument to a non-null default?
I end up doing a lot of something like this, what seems to be quiet ugly because it requires an additional val with a new name and I have to define the default twice.
fun foo(a: String? = "") {
 val nonNullA = a ?: ""
 // further processing which requires a to be non-null
}


You can handle the default value within the function body only, without define it twice:
fun foo(a: String? = null) {
    val nonNullA = a ?: ""
    // further processing which requires a to be non-null
}


If you want, you can even reuse the same name for the local val as the parameter name: @Suppress("NAME_SHADOWING") val a = a ?: ""

This is the right answer. From the caller's perspective it would otherwise be unclear what the difference is between the default value "" and null. Either forbid null and make the type non-nullable, then you can use "" as the default. Or make it nullable, and when you need the parameter to be optional, use null as the default.
